# MySQL database length

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How many records can a mysql database table have for optimal handling (when should I split it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no single correct answer to this question. It depends a lot on what data you store, what types of queries you run, how frequently you run queries, the capacity of your server, and other factors.

The time to split the database is when a single database instance cannot handle the volume of data you need, or the rate of queries you execute.

You may also split the database before that, when you can estimate growth in data volume or query traffic so you know it will exceed the capacity of one database instance.

Capacity planning and database scaling is a complex subject, more than can be answered by a mere Stack Overflow answer.